# Xamarn, AlarmManager dosn't fired at schedule time

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, alarmmanager

I have a problem with Alarm Manager that doesn't fired my schedule notification.

```
class MyNotification : INotification
    {
       private List<Note> ListNotes;
       Intent alarmIntent;
       DateTime baseTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1,0,0,0);

        public async void CreateScheduleNotifications()
       {
           ListNotes = await DataBaseService.getTimeActiveNotes();
           foreach(Note note in ListNotes )
            {               
                long scheduleAlarmTime = this.setScheduleAlarmTime(note.AlarmTime);  
                this.addNewScheduleNotification(note.Id,note.Title,note.Content,scheduleAlarmTime);
            }
        }

        private void addNewScheduleNotification(int id,string title, string content,long alarmTime)
        {
           alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.AndroidContext, typeof(AlamReciver));

            alarmIntent.PutExtra("id", id);
            alarmIntent.PutExtra("title", title);
            alarmIntent.PutExtra("content", content);

            var PI = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(MainActivity.AndroidContext, id, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)MainActivity.AndroidContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, alarmTime, PI);
        }

        private long setScheduleAlarmTime(DateTime noteAlarmTime)
        {
            TimeSpan calcTime = noteAlarmTime - baseTime;
            return (long)calcTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        }
    }
```

My "noteAlarmTime" format is (y,m,d,h,m,s).
It works perfect on emulator with API 23 and only there. On emulator with API 25 or my smartphones with API 23 or 25 doesn't work at all.

I tried modified this line

```
alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, alarmTime, PI);
```

to:

alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtime, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 5 * 1000, PI); 
and then notification is fired.

So why notification with schedule real time doesn't work?

Thank you.

Time calculation:

```
private long setScheduleAlarmTime(DateTime noteAlarmTime)
        {
            TimeSpan calcTime = noteAlarmTime.ToUniversalTime() - baseTime; 
            return (long)calcTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        }
```

Comment: It's calculated in method setScheduleAlarmTime

Comment: When I set alarm on 20:08 1.9.2017 in debug for "calcTime" I have: 17410. 20:08:00

Comment: For the same time is 1504297080000 miliseconds.

Comment: So in two hours the alarm should go off (150429708 = 09/01/2017 @ 8:18pm (UTC) and now equals 1504290587 = 09/01/2017 @ 6:29pm (UTC))

Comment: Sorry, one more time. On my emulator current time is 19:40 I set a alarm time to 20:30 1.9.2017 and I got 1504297800000 millisecond to alarm time. So when my alarm time should go off?

Comment: To double check your time based upon your device/timezone/..., grab an instance of an android calendar and set the milliseconds on it and debug/log the `Time` property, i.e.: `var cal = Calendar.Instance; cal.TimeInMillis = yourValue; Log.Debug("X", cal.Time.ToString());`

Comment: So, to have a proper alarm time calculation based on device timezone I have to convert "noteAlarmTime" to UTC? Code update above.Is it correct?